# node_access check against array of node ids

Tags: 7, users

I am in middle of a problem where i have to check node access of current user against an array of node ids.

I have a two content types (A and B) and one contains the reference of other based on a taxonomy. A contains a user role reference fields to allow access to certain roles only. Now i want to show related contents from A on detail page of B. I have used a custom query to fetch all nodes from A somehow related to B. So code is looks like:

```
$related_nodes = <function_to_get_related_node>;
$result = node_load_multiple($related_nodes);
```

I have restricted couple of node from A content type to display only certain user roles but $result shows all node from A. Node access not worked.

In my function i have used db_select() with addTag('node_access') but it doesn't seems to be working.

So Basically i want some sort of code to check node_access on array of $related_nodes and filter before it passed to node_load_multiple function.
Could someone help me find a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding checking if the node has reference of current user while fetching related nodes.

So,

```
$related_nodes = <get_related_node>;  

  // Might look Dumb
  function get_related_node($user=NULL) {
    if(is_null($user)) {
      global $user;
    }
    db_select('node','n')
     //Your existing joins
     // One more join for the user reference field, :O
     ->leftJoin('field_data_userreference','ur','ur.entity_id=n.nid')
     // your existing conditions for query.
     // One more condition for the current user as the value on the field.
     ->condition('ur.entity_id',$user->uid,'=')
    // And the execution continues.
  }
```

Fields mahcine names to be fixed as per the names provided. It should filter your reference nodes while fetching.

Comment: But i have a user role references field not a user. So i need to show only node which is allowed to view by current user role or anonymous if no role is selected.

Comment: in that case, instead of user id you would be intersted in comparing role ids of current user in query

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but assuming the reference field table (let's call it *"field_data_field_roles"*) is structured something like this:

```
entity_type | entity_id | field_roles_rid (role id)
```

...then this should return a new array of node ids filtered by the conditions described in your post:

```
global $user;

$rids = array_keys($user->roles); // array of role ids belonging to current user
$nids = array('1', '2', '3'); // array of node ids

$query = db_select('node','n');

// Set up the join, targeting the table containing the reference field data.
$query->join('field_data_field_roles', 'r', 'n.nid = r.entity_id');

// Declare your conditions. I threw in the 'node_access' tag, not knowing
// whether the check was applied when you retrieved the original set of nids.
$query
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('n.nid', $nids, 'IN')
  ->condition('r.field_roles_rid', $rids, 'IN')
  ->addTag('node_access');

// Fetch matching nids.
$result = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Cheers -